# How can I use the SSL while building a SOAP API?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, soap

I currently build a simple SOAP API in C#.

More specifically I just use the sample of the Visual Studio Project when it creates a WCF App, this is why I do not provide any code as it is the standard code.

How can I make the requests to require SSL Protocol when the clients make any Requests?

I have used this documentation to make the API , [getting-started-tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial).

Comment: SSL has been replaced with TLS 1.2/1.3.  There is no standard WCF code.  You have to provide the code that you are using.

Comment: To create an WCF application that uses SSL, use IIS to host the application. Alternatively, if you are creating a self-hosted application, use the HttpCfg.exe tool to bind an X.509 certificate to a specific port on a computer. The port number is specified as part of the WCF application as an endpoint address. Please refer to this link for related information about "Configure an IIS-hosted WCF service with SSL": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve a secure connection is to put HTTPS instead of HTTP:

```
Uri address = new Uri("https://example.com");
```

You can find more details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-secure-sockets-layer

> If the URI begins with "https:", SSL is used; if the URI begins with
> "http:", an unencrypted connection is used.

WCF service as any other web resource is **usually** managed and hosted by the webserver.
So, your task will be divided into two parts:

1. Configuration of the WCF service
2. Configuration of IIS

Better explained in this article:
[How to: Configure an IIS-hosted WCF service with SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl)

Comment: I mean how to make it to be mandatory for the requests , for example  if a client uses a method from the API , it have to have SSL  , I mean how to put it in the configuration that the API Requests have to use  SSL